# The same codes and different results

Tags: c++, qt

I want to ask you why these 2 codes aren't equivalent to each other?

Without GUI works fine:

```
string str; cin >> str;

for(int n=0;n<=str.length();n++){
    string total;
    total=conversion(str[n]);
}
```

...but with GUI(Qt) in output of the conversion function appears random chars:

```
string str = ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();

for( size_t n = 0; n <= str.length(); n++ ) {
string total;
total= conversion(str[n]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show any output you get (and where exactly you're printing this output)?

Comment: Have you verified that `ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString()` actually returns something meaningful?

Answer (score 6):

```
for(int n=0;n<=str.length();n++){
    string total;
    total=conversion(str[n]);
}
```

is undefined behaviour because of the out of bound access on `str`, you need

```
for(int n=0;n<str.length();n++){
    string total;
    total=conversion(str[n]);
}
```

If your programs have undefined behaviour they do strange things, like working in one situation but not working in another.

Comment: John Your idea does not change anything, i've printing output with that method: QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(total);
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText(qstr);
            msgBox.exec(); Output result: èÿÜûÿYèHGüÿÇ

Comment: Well perhaps a bug in `conversion` then. It's a bug *somewhere*.

Comment: Ok, I resolved the problem:   QString something = ui->lineEdit->text();
    string str= something.toLatin1();

    for( int n = 0; n < something.length(); n++ ) {..}